# Angular upload multiply files

Tags: angular

When i try to send files from input the request is NOT formdata

```
<input
  type="file"
  multiple
  (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)"
  accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"
/>
```

```
 public fileChangeEvent(event) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    console.log('e ', event.target.files);

    // for (const item of event.target.files) {
    //   formData.append('files[]', item, item.name);
    // }

    formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
    //
    this.http.post('feedback/img/upload', formData).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('res ', res);
    });
}
```

[image]
Request headers
[image]

what i did wrong? why it is not form data?

I have the same logic in another component with cropping image and there is formdata

```
public uploadImage() {
    const fileName = this.imageChangedEvent.target.files[0].name;
    const blob = this.b64toBlob(this.croppedImage);
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('file', blob, fileName);

    this.apiService.upload(
      'users/avatar/upload',
      formData,
      {
        reportProgress: true
      }
    ).then(res => {
      
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found interceptor wich set content-type to application/json.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Yours service

```
    upload(file: File) {
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        formData.append('file', file);
    
        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.url}/upload`, formData, {
          reportProgress: true,
          responseType: 'json'
        });
    
        return this.http.request(req);
      }
```

HTML:

```
<label>
  <input type="file" multiple (change)="selectFiles($event)" />
</label>

<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="uploadFiles()"  >
  Upload File
</button>
```

JS:

```
uploadFiles() {

  for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
    this.upload(i, this.selectedFiles[i]);
  }
}

upload(idx, file) {
  this.uploadService.upload(file).subscribe(
    event => {},
    err => {});
}
```